# Drop Down List only renders with selected item if the selection has more than 3 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my controller I pass a list of values to the view to be used as the options for a select element by selecting from my database as SelectListItems, which works well enough. The problem is that when passing a selected option back to the view, the select only renders with the selected value if the selection is more than 4 characters (or at least while trying to figure out why it was happening, it only happened with the ones less than 4 characters). It also works perfectly if I select something with 4 characters, and then something with less than 4. I'm not sure why this happens or how to fix it. Here's (what I believe to be) the relevant code:

The Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string selection = null){
    //code shortened for brevity
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selection))
    {
        ViewData["List"] = new SelectList(values.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c,
            Value = c
        }), "Value", "Text", selection);
        ViewData["Selection"] = selection;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <select asp-items="@ViewBag.List" name="selection" class="form-control" id="selectionDDL">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I actually think I found the problem: if the 'selection' variable was null I just sent that values as a selectlist directly back to the view, without specifying the value and text as I do in the 'if' portion of the block. Not sure why it would only then work with selections of more than 4 characters, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think I found the problem: if the 'selection' variable was null I just sent that 'values' variable as a selectlist directly back to the view, without specifying the value and text as I do in the 'if' portion of the block. Not sure why it would only then work with selections of more than 4 characters, but this fixed it.